# What is the correct way to define a controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a controller in AngularJS, and it works fine when i define it like this:

```
aluPlanetApp.controller('KontaktController', function($scope) {
  $scope.title= 'Kontakt';
  $scope.id = '10';
  $scope.users =[{"MIGX_id":"1","image":"upload/bridge.png"}];
});
```

However, when I define it like this I get an error:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    aluPlanetApp.controller('KontaktController', KontaktController);

    KontaktController.$inject = ['$scope']; 

    function KontaktController($scope) {
        $scope.title= 'Kontakt';
$scope.id = '10';
$scope.users =[{"MIGX_id":"1","image":"upload/bridge.png"}];

        activate();

        function activate() { }
    }
})();
```

This is the error I get:

> TypeError: aluPlanetApp.config(...) is not a function
>   aluPlanetApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

The entire JavaScript file is [here](http://www.aluplanet.rs/app.js).

Comment: You never declare `aluPlanetApp` as angular module for either version to work as shown. Something missing for first version to even work

Comment: I have declared in main page like this

 <script type="text/javascript">

        var aluPlanetApp = angular.module('aluPlanetApp', ['ngRoute','ngSanitize','ui.bootstrap','angular-carousel']);

    </script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of  `aluPlanetApp` variable completely and always use the getter version of `angular.module()`

```
angular.module('aluPlanetApp').controller(...
angular.module('aluPlanetApp').service(...
angular.module('aluPlanetApp').directive(...
```

See [John Papa Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y022)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the module first after 'use strict',

```
var aluPlanetApp = angular.module("aluPlanetApp");
```